# window.getSelection in ionic 3 / angular not working

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to get the selected text with window.getSelection. But it doesn't work. I don't get any error.

**HTML**

```
<span (mouseup)="showSelectedText()" id="descriptionText" class="val descriptionText" [innerHTML]="descriptionText"></span>
```

**JS**

```
showSelectedText(oField) {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
        console.log('text: ' + text)
  this.selectedText = text;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to solve it. Maybe someone is looking for it.

**HTML**

```
<span #desc (mouseup)="pressEvent($event)" id="descriptionText" class="val descriptionText" [innerHTML]="descriptionText"></span>
```

**JS**

```
pressEvent(e) {
      var parentEl = null, sel;
      if (window.getSelection) {
        var s = window.getSelection();
          if (s && s.rangeCount > 0) {
            if (window.getSelection) {
                  if (s.rangeCount) {
                            parentEl = s.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
                            if (parentEl.nodeType != 1) {
                                parentEl = parentEl.parentNode;
                                }
                      }
                        }
                        else if ( (s = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
                           parentEl = s.createRange().parentElement();
                        }

                      const p = JSON.stringify(parentEl);
                      const pt = JSON.parse(p);
                      if (pt.__zone_symbol__mouseupfalse) {
                            // start getSelectedWord
                            this.getSelectedWord(s);
                      }
          };
        }
  }


getSelectedWord(s) {
    var range = s.getRangeAt(0);
    var node = s.anchorNode;
    while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') != 0) {
      range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));
    }
    range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
    do {
      range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);

    }
    while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') == -1 && range.toString().trim() != '');
    var str = range.toString().trim();
    console.log(str)
  }
```